# Проблема со сглаживанием тайлов в Unity

Tags: unity3d, спрайт

Нарисовал тайлы и, с помощью `TileMap`, создал карту. У тайлсета выставил билинейное сглаживание. Естественно, между тайлами образовались полосы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скриншот с еще большим приближением:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В интернете куча советов по типу: убрать сглаживание и отображать пиксель в пиксель. **Но** тогда при отдалении камеры и во время ее движения получается пиксельная каша (так как спрайты получаются сильно уменьшены).

**Собственно сам вопрос:**
Можно ли выставить сглаживание так, что бы оно не задевало края спрайтов? Ну или сглаживать все тайлы вместе после их отрисовки, как один большой спрайт?

Короче говоря, нужно сгладить спрайты тайлов, но убрать полосы между ними. Это вообще возможно осуществить средствами Unity?

**Upd: эти полосы - не промежутки между тайлами, как я думал, а, видимо, части соседних спрайтов из атласа. Попробую оставить промежутки между тайлами в атласе**

Comment: А это у вас случаем не сетка поверх нарисована? Ведь там еще видны клетки 1/5.

Comment: Нет. Это именно дырки между тайлами. Сейчас добавлю еще один скрин бо'льшим с увеличением

Comment: Я столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Как ты её решил, моет помнишь, спрашиваю потому что вопрос задан 2 года назад.

Comment: не зря спросил) а то я два года назад забыл ответ добавить. я добавил в атласе  зазор в два пикселя между тайлами, и заполнил его цветом из ближайших пикселей. (условно, в фотошопе раздвинул тайлы, чтобы между ними было расстояние 2пикселя, сдублировал на новый слой снизу, и увеличил каждый дублированный тайл на 1 пискель во все стороны). Таким образом, когда Unity сглаживает атлас, то крайние пиксели визуально не изменяются. Ведь они соседние с такими же пикселями(которые мы продублировали по краям каждого тайла)

Answer (score 0):

Поставте максимальный размер спрайта в 4098 , мне помогло

Answer (score -1):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой, мне помогло вот это:
Edit>Project Settings>Quality>Anti Aliasing:Disabled